Issues with Double Gaussian Fit Using curve_fit in Python
I used find_peaks to locate the peaks and estimated the initial parameters for the double Gaussian fit. I expected the curve_fit function to accurately fit the double Gaussian to my data, aligning the peaks and widths correctly. However, the resulting fit does not match the data well, and the Gaussian peaks are misaligned.
Is there a way to achieve a more accurate fit?
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy.signal import find_peaks
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

# Data arrays
y_data = np.array([
    1.500e-04, 1.500e-04, 1.500e-04, 1.500e-04, 1.700e-04, 1.600e-04, 1.800e-04,
    1.600e-04, 1.700e-04, 2.300e-04, 2.500e-04, 3.200e-04, 3.200e-04, 3.800e-04,
    4.000e-04, 5.000e-04, 5.600e-04, 5.600e-04, 6.500e-04, 7.500e-04, 9.100e-04,
    1.180e-03, 1.550e-03, 2.110e-03, 2.880e-03, 3.850e-03, 5.200e-03, 6.780e-03,
    8.950e-03, 1.123e-02, 1.403e-02, 1.723e-02, 2.031e-02, 2.330e-02, 2.495e-02,
    2.433e-02, 2.171e-02, 1.725e-02, 1.231e-02, 8.080e-03, 4.980e-03, 2.960e-03,
    1.970e-03, 1.830e-03, 2.220e-03, 2.880e-03, 3.700e-03, 4.650e-03, 5.820e-03,
    7.150e-03, 8.450e-03, 9.510e-03, 1.006e-02, 9.660e-03, 8.560e-03, 6.910e-03,
    5.100e-03, 3.380e-03, 2.170e-03, 1.230e-03, 7.000e-04, 3.600e-04, 2.200e-04,
    1.700e-04, 1.500e-04, 1.600e-04, 1.100e-04, 1.100e-04, 1.200e-04, 1.000e-04,
    1.200e-04, 1.100e-04, 1.300e-04, 1.500e-04, 1.200e-04, 1.600e-04, 1.200e-04,
    1.200e-04, 1.200e-04, 1.200e-04, 1.100e-04, 1.500e-04, 1.500e-04, 1.300e-04,
    1.100e-04, 8.000e-05, 1.200e-04, 1.200e-04, 1.100e-04, 1.100e-04, 1.500e-04])

x_data = np.array([
    6555.101, 6555.201, 6555.301, 6555.401, 6555.501, 6555.601, 6555.701, 6555.801,
    6555.901, 6556.001, 6556.101, 6556.201, 6556.301, 6556.401, 6556.501, 6556.601,
    6556.701, 6556.801, 6556.901, 6557.001, 6557.101, 6557.201, 6557.301, 6557.401,
    6557.501, 6557.601, 6557.701, 6557.801, 6557.901, 6558.001, 6558.101, 6558.201,
    6558.301, 6558.401, 6558.501, 6558.601, 6558.701, 6558.801, 6558.901, 6559.001,
    6559.101, 6559.201, 6559.301, 6559.401, 6559.501, 6559.601, 6559.701, 6559.801,
    6559.901, 6560.001, 6560.101, 6560.201, 6560.301, 6560.401, 6560.501, 6560.601,
    6560.701, 6560.801, 6560.901, 6561.001, 6561.101, 6561.201, 6561.301, 6561.401,
    6561.501, 6561.601, 6561.701, 6561.801, 6561.901, 6562.001, 6562.101, 6562.201,
    6562.301, 6562.401, 6562.501, 6562.601, 6562.701, 6562.801, 6562.901, 6563.001,
    6563.101, 6563.201, 6563.301, 6563.401, 6563.501, 6563.601, 6563.701, 6563.801,
    6563.901, 6564.001, 6564.001])

# Find peaks
peaks, _ = find_peaks(y_data, height=0.0005)

# Define double Gaussian function
def double_gaussian(x, a1, b1, c1, a2, b2, c2):
    g1 = a1 * np.exp(-((x - b1) ** 2) / (2 * c1 ** 2))
    g2 = a2 * np.exp(-((x - b2) ** 2) / (2 * c2 ** 2))
    return g1 + g2

# Function to find Full Width at Half Maximum (FWHM)
def find_fwhm(x, y, peak_index):
    half_max = y[peak_index] / 2
    left_idx = np.where(y[:peak_index] <= half_max)[0][-1]
    right_idx = np.where(y[peak_index:] <= half_max)[0][0] + peak_index
    left_x = x[left_idx] + (half_max - y[left_idx]) * (x[left_idx + 1] - x[left_idx]) / (y[left_idx + 1] - y[left_idx])
    right_x = x[right_idx] + (half_max - y[right_idx]) * (x[right_idx + 1] - x[right_idx]) / (y[right_idx + 1] - y[right_idx])
    return right_x - left_x

# Calculate FWHM for each peak
fwhm1 = find_fwhm(x_data, y_data, peaks[0]) / 2.355
fwhm2 = find_fwhm(x_data, y_data, peaks[1]) / 2.355

# Initial guess for the parameters
initial_guess = [y_data[peaks[0]], x_data[peaks[0]], fwhm1, y_data[peaks[1]], x_data[peaks[1]], fwhm2]

# Fit the data using curve_fit
params, covariance = curve_fit(double_gaussian, x_data, y_data, p0=initial_guess)

# Generate fitted data
x_fit = np.linspace(min(x_data), max(x_data), 10000)
fitted_data = double_gaussian(x_fit, *params)

# Separate the two Gaussian components
g1 = params[0] * np.exp(-((x_fit - params[1]) ** 2

) / (2 * params[2] ** 2))
g2 = params[3] * np.exp(-((x_fit - params[4]) ** 2) / (2 * params[5] ** 2))

# Plot the data and the fit
plt.scatter(x_data, y_data, label='Data')
plt.plot(x_fit, g1, 'g--', label='Gaussian 1')
plt.plot(x_fit, g2, 'm--', label='Gaussian 2')
plt.plot(x_fit, fitted_data, 'r--', label='Double Gaussian')
plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('y')
plt.legend()
plt.show()

And here is the resulting plot:


Data are not exactly gaussian, where those data come from? Chromatography?

The data comes from hydrogen and deuterium spectroscopy.

Then Doppler effect affects your peaks and they are not purely gaussian. Voigt profile is what you are looking for.

When data are not exactly Gaussian (peaks have bigger tailing, even in a small extent), it is a common approach to fit a Voigt or a Pseudo-Voigt (which is easier to compute) profile instead of Gaussian.
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import optimize, stats

We define the Pseudo Voigt peak:
def pseudo_voigt(x, eta, sigma, gamma, x0, A):
    G = stats.norm.pdf(x, scale=sigma, loc=x0)
    L = stats.cauchy.pdf(x, scale=2. * gamma, loc=x0)
    return A * ((1. - eta) * G + eta * L)

And the model for double peaks:
def model2(x, eta0, sigma0, gamma0, x00, A0, eta1, sigma1, gamma1, x01, A1):
    return pseudo_voigt(x, eta0, sigma0, gamma0, x00, A0) + pseudo_voigt(x, eta1, sigma1, gamma1, x01, A1)

We fit:
popt2, pcov2 = optimize.curve_fit(
    model2,
    x_data, y_data,
    p0=[0.5, 1., 1., 6559, 0.025, 0.5, 1., 1., 6561, 0.01],
    bounds=[
         (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
         (1, np.inf, np.inf, np.inf, np.inf, 1, np.inf, np.inf, np.inf, np.inf)
    ]
)
# array([5.04788238e-01, 3.39173299e-01, 2.55686905e-01, 6.55847681e+03,
#        2.75922544e-02, 3.34888395e-19, 3.35457589e-01, 4.01394103e+00,
#        6.56029885e+03, 7.93603468e-03])

Results is not totally perfect:

But at least the first peak reach its nominal height and its tailing is taken into account.

You have many, many more points on the wings than you do at the top of each curve, so relatively speaking the location of the curve peak is not particularly important in the fit result.
You could change this by weighting the points so that the model more strongly weights points near the peak. For example, with this change:
params, covariance = curve_fit(double_gaussian, x_data, y_data, p0=initial_guess, sigma=1./y_data)

The final fit looks like this:

The fit still is not perfect near the leftmost points; I suspect the reason is that your data is not actually drawn from a double-gaussian.
